# Android iframe vimeo player controls disappear

Tags: android, iframe, webview, vimeo

I have a WebView that loads Vimeo videos fine and plays them, however, once a video starts playing, the player controls (play/pause) disappear and there doesn't seem to be a way to get them back. Here's the code:

```
videoView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String videoHtml = "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/37551417\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>";
videoView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
videoView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", videoHtml , "text/html",  "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Probably very related to this I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48831109/5911613, not a proper solution but I hope it helps.